# How do I get body of every mails of my gmail account using gmail api?

Tags: python, google-oauth, gmail-api, python-3.7, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to parse each and every mail body from my gmail account using google oauth and gmail api services. As per now I can only get the messages id and thread id, when I open them it doesn't make sense at all.
So the following code I have used that are as below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    print(service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute())
    print(service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id='16931216e3a05048').execute())
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the output I got is like this for one of the message id using this line `print(service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id='16931216e3a05048').execute())`

the output is like this:
[image: this is the output I have been getting using the above piece of code]

Comment: what I want is email body of every mail where we can get specific details that we need, like how can we get to know if the person is subscirbed to that channel, blogs or any sites.

I'm really stuck, I don't want only the message snippet, that I have been getting by now. Help me guys

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the format

[messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

[image]

```
message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,
                                         format='raw').execute()

print 'Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet']

msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
```

Comment: hey bro, I don't only want the message snippet and what the output I got is like this with some error on it
"Message snippet: Hi AdityaMandal, Greetings from GeeksforGeeks! Have you heard about Python- The Programming Language? If yes, then we have a wonderful surprise for you! And don&#39;t feel low if you don&#39;t know"

Comment: and the errror I got is like this
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sToNeR\Desktop\gmail\quickstart\quickstart.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\sToNeR\Desktop\gmail\quickstart\quickstart.py", line 42, in main
    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
NameError: name 'base64' is not defined*

Comment: even though I forgot to imort some module like bas64 and email.mime.text and then when I ran again, I got the message snippet as follows but not the whole mail body and ended up with this error below

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sToNeR\Desktop\gmail\quickstart\quickstart.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\sToNeR\Desktop\gmail\quickstart\quickstart.py", line 46, in main
    mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
  File "E:\Python 3\lib\email\__init__.py", line 38, in message_from_string
    return Parser(*args, **kws).parsestr(s)
  File "E:\Python 3\lib\email\parser.py", line 68, in parsestr
    return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes